# What happen if 1 user login at 2 different browser/device and buying 1 item simultaneously?

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency, transactions

So imagine i have a website (PHP + MYSQL) and my site have a login page and sell Banana, and my site also have "Credits" users can top up via paypal to add more credits.

Imagine user1 have $1 in their credits and 1 banana cost $1, What if user1 Login at 2 different devices and buying 1 banana simultaneously, does it count as 2 banana buyed or 1 banana buyed and another banana rejected ?

And if 2 banana is buyed, is that any way to prevent this MULTIPLE SIMULTANEOUSLY REQUEST ?

Comment: That depends how you write your application...

Comment: "And if 2 banana is buyed, is that any way to prevent this "...why would you want to, unless there's only 1 left in stock?

Comment: @ADyson Lets say i have unlimited stock, how to prevent this problem ?

Comment: One basic idea would be to use transactions in the database and then it should ensure that it checks the latest credit level before it processes each request

Comment: @ADyson Any sample code ? or searching suggestion ?

Comment: Learn about SQL transactions first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be good practice to do this process as a single transaction.
That way, the data is read, processed and then created/updated in good timing. This in itself would be feasible as the two transactions would not run concurrently.

```
($pdo = new PDO))->beginTransaction();
$read = $pdo->Prepare(“Some select statement”);
$read->execute(array(‘someVal’));
if(($row = $read->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) && (float) $row->wallet >= 1.0) {
    $update = $pdo->Prepare(‘Some update wallet statement’):
    $update->execute();
    $create = $pdo->Prepare(“create a new transaction”);
    $create->execute(array(‘some val’));
}
$pdo->commit();
```

Alternatively, or for extra precaution, you could implant a minor random wait time between scripts executing to prevent timed attacks but the network latency should stop this.

Update: I want to touch on security. Although PDO (if used correctly with emulate prepares set to false) does prevent most common vulnerabilities like SQL injections, transactions are subject to race conditions. Ensure you limit the block chain and are following security procedures to ensure race conditions are limited.

Comment: "... as the two transactions would not run concurrently." what if there is 10000 user buying 1 banana, and lets say 1 transaction takes 1 second, does the 9999th transaction need to wait 9999seconds ?

Comment: You would wait milliseconds & one user would only wait a few milliseconds.. PHP is stateless, other “users” would not elapse time continuously.. you could of course use a load balancer instead. @BeastBro

Answer (score 3):

This problem is harder to solve than it looks.

You wish to prevent the same user logged in from two different locations from buying the same item at the same time.

The cleanest way to do this is to prevent different sessions for the same user from using your "buy" page. But even that is hard: how will know the chromebook is done with the buy page before the mac tries to use it?

If you implement your buy page stuff correctly, the user who orders bananas from both her chromebook and her mac will receive and pay for two bananas. That's because you'll use a [database *transaction*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) to complete each order, and your two transactions on behalf of the same user will, necessarily, run one after the other.

**Edit** Transaction capability is a major feature of database systems, including MySQL and others. E-commerce web applications use these transactions to make sure concurrent ordering attempts don't produce inconsistent results, and to make sure they don't accept another order right after somebody just ordered the last banana in stock. The bad  news: handling these transactions in enormous databases is very hard to get right. The good news: major database system developers (MySQL, postgreSql, IBM DB2, Oracle, SQL Server, and the rest) have been working on it for decades and their transactions are reliable.

E-commerce vendors generally allow the same user to log in from different devices at the same time and place orders.

If you really want to avoid this kind of duplicate order, your buy page needs logic to say, "hey, you ordered a banana from your mac less than five minutes ago, you're not allowed to order another one from a different device right now. Try again later."

But, as you can imagine, getting the business rules exactly right for this kind of logic will be difficult.

Comment: I wonder how big company avoid this Multiple Simultaneously Request ?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: "...you'll use a database transaction to complete each order, and your two transactions on behalf of the same user will, necessarily, run one after the other." Lets say there is 10000 user buying banana, does this method will make my website run slower ?

Comment: Multiple requests concurrently would be placed in a queue and execute accordingly...

Comment: Database technology suppliers brag endlessly about how many transactions per second they can handle. If you build scaled-up web sites these days you stand on the shoulders of giants.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check the "stock" table at the point of processing the order, depending on your expected throughput of transactions to prevent multiple purchases of the same item you could create a stored procedure that will lock the check the stock and place the order with the tables locked.

For the issue of unlimited stock but limited funds you can do the same thing by processing the transactions one at a time, you must "lock" the tables to check the "bank" before making the order and returning this result. When the second order gets to the front of the queue it will once again check the balance as part of the ordering process and will see they have no more funds.

Comment: Let's say i have unlimited stock, how to prevent this problem ?

Comment: @BeastBro Is your intention to prevent the user from ordering them in a certain timeframe or just outright only 1?

Comment: Create a random wait time interval between actions. This will slow your script down by a fraction of a second but also prevent timed attacks although any latency would make this hard to achieve anyway. Also good practice to check the record before updating it (don’t carry over sensitive data within the request and do not hold onto it for a while)

Comment: @User1010 only 1, im afraid user1 can order 2 (or more maybe) banana with only $1 Credits.

Comment: @Jaquarh im thinking about that too, but i think that method will just only make my website slower

Comment: @BeastBro I have updated my answer, the same principle applies in that they must be processed one at a time to ensure absolute accuracy.

Comment: @User1010 i think "one at a time" method just only make my website slower, and what if i have 1000 users buying banana at one time? My website will run very slow i think.

Comment: @BeastBro This can be handled by a stored procedure containing a transaction, for funds you only need to do one at a time per customer but for stock as well it needs to be one across the store for absolute accuracy.

Comment: @User1010 any sample code ? or searching suggestion ?

Comment: @User1010 "...for funds you only need to do one at a time per customer...". What if there is 10000 user buying 1 banana, and lets say 1 transaction takes 1 second, does the 9999th transaction need to wait 9999seconds ?